# Making a specific form invisible on page with multiple forms

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, mongodb

I have multiple forms on a page. Each form has a submit button.

When I click submit on a form it should become invisible. The forms not yet submitted should remain visible.

I do not want to refresh the page as each form is submitted.

I am using Node.js, Express.js and mongodb.

Comment: Use... Browser-side JavaScript.. `document.getElementById("MyForm").style.display = "none";`

Comment: Simple  you can do this either `Angular` ot `jquery`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-form]').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      //do some ajax if needed
      e.currentTarget.remove()
    })
})
```

I have created an example fiddle for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/aw9aL8mf/

Comment: I believe what you have shown is a client side script. How do I save the form content to mongo db after submitting? Thank you.

Comment: You can not do that only from server-side without a page refresh. It is impossible. You can not handle browser click event in Express.js and you can not re-render a page from server-side without client-side js.

Comment: Okay. Currently, I am re-rendering the page every time a form is submitted. But, I am having problem removing that submitted form when I reload the page. Do you have any suggestions for this kind of issue? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, first of all, you will need a template engine to send data to the templates from the controller. ([Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)). In a very very basic example, you should have a property in every form in mongo called `shouldRender`. It is true by default, and if the from is posted set it to false. In the template use this variable {{#if shouldRender}}<form>...</form>{{/if}} I hope you understand it, if not, feel free to ask.